# How to remove the encrypt option permanently for a desktop folder?

Tags: windows

How to remove the encrypt option permanently for a desktop folder.

I clicked the desktop folder, right click - properties – advanced – removed the “encrypt contents to secure data” option.

When I am creating or copying a folder or file in desktop, the folder and files are automatically encrypting.

How to remove the option permanently?

Comment: Creating files and folders on the windows desktop does not necessarily encrypt them, it depends on the configuration of the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've removed the Encrypt option on your desktop folder itself.  If that is enabled then any folders you create on your desktop will also be encrypted.  It's default locations are:

Windows XP and earlier:

```
c:\documents and settings\[username]\Desktop
```

Windows Vista and later:

```
c:\users\[username]\Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all folders in the hierarchy have encryption turned off, as **inheritance** will do this. Starting from the desktop folder (that `squillman` pointed out) make sure it is not encrypted, then move up a directory and make sure its previous folder is not encrypted, until you get to `C:\`.